# Set visibility on a group of items

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to wrap all of these and bind to a single visibility
I want them all to still use their row and column

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text="Caution don't use Lock on the main Search page.  Both will be applied." 
            Margin="4,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Coded" Margin="7,2,0,0" 
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchItem.Coded}"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Locked (must ✓ Coded and not ✓ Predicted)" Margin="7,2,0,0" 
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchItem.Locked}"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Predicted" Margin="7,2,0,0"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchItem.Predicted}"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="Rank 1" Margin="7,2,0,0"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchItem.Rank1}"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="Rank 2" Margin="5,2,0,0"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchItem.Rank2}"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Content="Rank 3" Margin="5,2,0,0"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchItem.Rank3}"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Content="Rank 4
```

Comment: Add a `Visibility` to each and use the same binding, or put them in some "container" that has `Visitility` set?

Comment: @crashmstr The question is how to wrap them all to a single visibility.  Not how to bind them all to the same visibility.  It is more about code readability than the time to copy paste.

Comment: "wrap all of these and bind to a single visibility"... well, put them in a stack panel or grid and give it a visibility, *or* bind them to a single visibility. Not sure how the difference really matters that much as long as they are where you want and are visible or not like you want.

Answer (score 0):

wrap everything inside of a Panel and then as you toggle the Visibility on and off, whatever is contained inside of the panel will show and hide as well.

Comment: OP said *I want them all to still use their row and column*

Comment: Panel alone does not work.  And I lose column with Stack and Wrap.  I thought for sure there would be a simple way to do this.